# Flutter: How to invoke existing sound file?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package, soundfile

I need to make an app, which can analyze existing sound files and get the frequencies of them.

As for analyzing frequencies, I plan to use fft. But as for invoking sound files, I don't know how to do in Flutter. Is there any useful packages which can help me invoking existing sound files?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By "invoking", do you mean playing the sound files?

Comment: No, I just want to get sound files and try analyzing them.